# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency- Mobx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mobx

I am using mobx and react hooks together .  I have a useContext to get the store functions

```
const store = useContext(MyStore)
useEffect(() => {
        if (init !== '') {
            store.loading = true;
            store.bulkApprove(init).then(data => {
                store.unCheckAll();
            });
        }
    }, [init]);
```

I can see bunch of warnings like below

```
 React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'store'. Either include it or remove the dependency array
```

**I am really confused why do i need to include the store on dependency array**

Comment: Yeah, i've been down this road. I've spent many hours trying to write my hooks in a way that satisfies the linter... The linter insists that everything touched within the function also exists within its `dependencies`. I have decided to ignore this until this either they update the linter, I find another way to write my hooks more effectively or if this becomes a problem. I know this isn't what your looking for though, thought it might help though.

Comment: React hook linter is build to provide guidance and adding all variables into dependency is one good practice. However it would be up to you to decide which variable to the hook to dependent on to trigger a re-render cycle within useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: <dep>. Either include it or remove the dependency array` simply means that the linter is warning you that you have a dependency that relies on an external value that may change.

`store` is subscribed to context `MyStore`. Meaning it is tracking its changes.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking I found a working solution on youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FS3pJa6rME

You basically wrap the store with a context and then wrap your function in an observer. This solution gets around the syntax hell I found myself in.

My store looks like this:

```
   import { observable, decorate, action } from "mobx";
   import { createContext } from "react";
   class NewsFormStore {
     formValues = [];
     onChange = (name, value) => {
       this.formValues[name] = value;
     };
   }
   decorate(NewsFormStore, {
     formValues: observable,
     onChange: action
   });

   export const store = new NewsFormStore();
   export const StoreContext = createContext(store);
```

Using the store for a simple textField can look like this:

```
   import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
   import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
   import { StoreContext } from "../../../../Stores/NewsFormStore";

   export const OutlinedTextFields = observer(props => {
   const store = useContext(StoreContext);
   const classes = useStyles();
   const [label] = useState(props.label !== "" ? props.label : "");
   const [name] = useState(props.name !== "" ? props.name : "");

   return (

      <TextField
        value={store.formValues[name]}
        onChange={e => store.onChange(name, e.target.value)}
        onBlur={e => store.onChange(name, e.target.value)}
        label={label}
        name={name}
      />

     );
   });
   export default OutlinedTextFields;
```